# How to bring elements closer together as the screen narrows?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, margin, overlap

I am using negative margin to cause some playing card elements to overlap, creating a visual effect akin to how a hand of playing cards  appear in real life.

The issue here is that the negative margin is defined in `vw`. This means that as the screen size widens, the value of a single `vw` becomes greater, and the negative margin grows, causing the cards to overlap *more*. This is contradictory to my intentions-- as the screen widens, the cards should spread accordingly, and overlap more as the screen narrows.

If I instead use an absolute value like `px`, the overlap will remain constant as the screen size changes, which is also undesirable.

I have spent many hours trial & erroring this and have yet to come up with a scheme that works correctly.

How can you cause a negative margin to diminish as the screen increases, with CSS *or* with JS if CSS can't do it alone?

Comment: On the container element, you can use `padding: nvw` or `padding: nem`
Where n is your numbe rof choice. Sorry, if I am wrong, tho

Comment: What are `nvw` and `nem`? I don't see those documented anywhere.

Comment: for ex . `1.5em` or `10vw` . `n` just means percentage of number of screen width: whatever unit you choose

Comment: You can use `display: flex`  and `align-content: space-between` on the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/ExKEmzG)

You could combine `clamp()` with `relative` positioning. You'll probably need to adjust the values a little to make it good looking, but this is the core concept.

```css
:root {
  --cardWidth: 200px;
  
  --min: calc(var(--cardWidth) / 8);
  --var: 7.5vw;
  --max: calc((var(--cardWidth) / 4) * 7);
  
  --overlap: clamp(
    var(--min),
    var(--var),
    var(--max)
  );
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.w {
  display: flex;
}

[class*=card] {
  height: 300px;
  width: var(--cardWidth);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px #000;
}

.card-2 {
  position: relative;
  left: calc((var(--cardWidth) * -1) + var(--overlap));
}
```

```html
<div class="c"></div>

<div class="w">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. You managed to do in a short while what I couldn't do all night. I applaud you. Thank you. Will this still work if the card sizes are relative to the screen size, too? I'm not able to try it right now, but just trying to picture it when I switch the 200px for Xvw.

Comment: @temporary_user_name, Thanks! Yes, should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use flex box for this. Try out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ .

Comment: Could you expand on how flexbox would accomplish this?